# How to go back to a previous line of code in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently learning C# and trying to go back to execute a a previous line. I have not found any ways to do this so far so I'm looking for help

```
int wants;

Console.WriteLine("What do you need? 1 - Links, 2 - Tasks or 3 - Misc");
wants = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            
switch (wants) 
{
      case 1:
          Console.WriteLine("The line");
          break;
      case 2:
          Console.WriteLine("The line");
          break;
      case 3:
          Console.WriteLine("You have none as of current sir");
          break;
      default:
          Console.WriteLine("Then why are you here...");
          Console.WriteLine("Because you cant decide?");
          Console.WriteLine("That must be it");
          //Go back to top of question
          break;
}
```

Comment: You can write loops (`while` or `for`). You can't jump backward arbitrarily.

Comment: Also, `c` is not `c#`. They're two completely different languages.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements

Comment: Just drag the arrow pointing to the current line to the previous line in Visual Studio

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [Repeating execution of code line(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do that might be the following:

```cs
var done = false;
while (!done)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What do you need? 1 - Links, 2 - Tasks or 3 - Misc, 4 - Quit");

    var input = Console.ReadLine();

    int.TryParse(input, out var wants);

    switch (wants)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("The line");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("The line");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("You have none as of current sir");
            break;
        case 4:
            done = true;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Then why are you here...");
            Console.WriteLine("Because you cant decide?");
            Console.WriteLine("That must be it");
            //Go back to top of question
            break;
    }
}
```

This is just an example to give you an idea.

You also should look into the do{}while(); construct.

```
bool finished = false;
do
{
    // body of do while loop
    // get input from user and do something
    // set finished true when done with the loop
    finished = true;
} while (!finished);
```

https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/do-while-loop#google_vignette

Comment: In the case of single- char choices, I personally would rather use `ReadKey`. Spares you from parsing,...

Comment: @Fildor Agreed. I just basically wrapped the OP's code in a while(). Others modified my answer and changed the OP's original code.

Comment: that's perfect - never thought to wrap it like that. thanks all